# Is there any isomorphism from $\mathbb R^*$ to $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Is there any isomorphism from $\mathbb R^*$ to $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb Z_2$?

I have tried so much but I fail to find such isomorphism,if any.Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of isomorphism? A group isomorphism? With which operation do you endow $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: Define a map $f : \mathbb R^* \longrightarrow \mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb Z_2$ by $f(m) = (|m|,[m])$.Then I think it will work.Isn't it?

Comment: @Rnbmath Reducing a number modulo 2 tells you nothing about its sign. The point of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ piece is to keep track of the sign.

Comment: In addition, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has two elements, and reducing the reals modulo 2 gives you much more than that.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions is malformed. But to make sense of it, I will make the following assumptions:

$$\mathbb{R}^* \text{ and } \mathbb{R}^+ \text{ are being viewed as groups under multiplication.}$$

Then you can check that:

$$\varphi : \mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$

defined by 
$$
\varphi(r) =\begin{cases}
 (|r|, 0) & \text{ if } r > 0 \\
(|r|,1) & \text{ if } r < 0 
\end{cases}
$$
is a group isomorphism.

Here we are viewing $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as an additive group.